# Django: INSTALLED_APPS is ".apps.AppConfig" redundant?

Tags: python, django, django-settings

I didn't see an answered version of this question, and this has really been bothering me because I've seen both be used.

In this example "myapp" is the created app.

I keep seeing users setup their apps inside of the INSTALLED_APPS list like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

instead of

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'myapp.apps.MyappConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]
```

So I have 2 questions

1. Is adding the "apps.MyappConfig" after "myapp" redundant?
2. If there is some importance to it, what is it?

Comment: Not per se, for example if there are multiple `AppConfig`s.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Is adding the "apps.MyappConfig" after "myapp" redundant?

Often yes, but **not always**. If you do not specify the `AppConfig` in the `INSTALLED_APP` yourself, then Django will look for the `default_app_config` variable in the module, as is specified in the documentation:

> When `INSTALLED_APPS` contains the dotted path to an application module, Django **checks for a `default_app_config` variable in that module**.

For example in the [`django.contrib.sessions` module <sup>[GitHub]</sup>](https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/3.0.x/django/contrib/sessions/__init__.py), we see:

> ```
> default_app_config = 'django.contrib.sessions.apps.SessionsConfig'
> ```

It is however possible to define multiple `AppConfig`s in a module, that each slighly alter the behavior of the application. See next section:

2. If there is some importance to it, what is it?

An [**`AppConfig`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig) is a class in your application that contains meta-data about the application. It contains for example the name of the app, the label, the path, et. Furthermore you can override methods like [**`.ready()`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/applications/#django.apps.AppConfig.ready). This method will be called if the models are loaded, and is often used to do some administrative tasks, or load signals when Django starts.

We can make multiple `AppConfig`s, for example one for development, one for production, and one for testing. But that does not happen that often.

Answer (score 8):

From [Django's docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/applications/#configuring-applications):

> To configure an application, subclass AppConfig and put the dotted path to that subclass in INSTALLED_APPS.

and

> If there is no default_app_config, Django uses the base AppConfig class

**If you need to add extra app configurations (e.g. importing Signals), you can do so in your app config** and would then need to include it in your `INSTALLED_APPS`. **Otherwise, you can include only your app in the `INSTALLED_APPS`**

So to answer your questions:

> Is adding the "apps.MyappConfig" after "myapp" redundant?

No

> If there is some importance to it, what is it?

Yes, adding extra config