# How to import urls from apps in django main urls file

Tags: python, django

I have the following project structure.

[image: Django Project Structure]

This is my INSTALLED_APPS array.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'climemanage.clients'
]
```

Then I tried to add the `clients.urls` file in the parent `urls` file as the below.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('clients/', include('clients.urls'))
]
```

But I'm getting this error. `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clients'`

I can solve this by using the following path. `include('climemanage.clients.urls')` but I want to skip `climemanage` from the path.

I have tried different ways as,

```
import clients
import climemanage.clients
from climemanage import clients
```

But nothing is working.

Comment: Your project directory looks very different from all my Django projects. Is it your intention to make this way? Or this is the structure you get after run start project command?

Comment: @ha-neul this is the structure that I got after the running commands.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your project structure is wrong. It seems either `startproject` part or `startapp` part might gone wrong. It might be best if you could list out how you got up to this point. Please see the structure I put at the end of my answer.

In your case, your main `settings.py` is under `clients`. This means that `clients` is the result of `startproject`. Currently you do not have an `app`, but you have a bunch of files that should be appeared with `app` that now under `migrations` folder.

Beause of that, you will never be able to add anything from `clients.urls` to main `urls.py`. Because your `clients` is the place where your main `urls.py` located.

I put what I normally do here (this mac version, if you are using windows, you need check django tutorial)

```
$ mkdir clienmanage
$ cd clienmanage
$ python3 -m venv myvenv      # set up virtual environment
$ source myvenv/bin/activate  # go into virtual envionment
After this step you can install django
```

then after that, when you run your `startproject` command, make sure run like below:

```
django-admin startproject project .
```

Note the `.` at the end.

After that, you should have structure like:

```
clienmanage
|--- manage.py
|--- project
|   |--- __init__.py
|   |--- settings.py
|   |--- urls.py
|   |--- wsgi.py
|--- virtual
|
|___ requirements.txt
```

then you will:

```
$ python manage.py startapp clients
```

```
clienmanage
|
|---clients # this is the app
|    |---migrations
|    |---models.py
|    |---views.py
|    |---apps.py  
|--- manage.py
|--- project
|   |--- __init__.py
|   |--- settings.py
|   |--- urls.py
|   |--- wsgi.py
|--- virtual # a folder
|
|___ requirements.txt
```

After this step, django will not automatically generate `app` level `urls.py` and `forms.py`. You should generate these files inside the `app` folder (in my example case, `clients`)

******If you want to put app in a different directory**
You can specify destination.

```
$ python manage.py startapp <app_label> [destination]
```

in the above case, if you want to have your `app` inside of `project`

```
$ python manage.py startapp clients project/clients
```

If you took this route, make sure to add `project.clients` rather than `clients` in your `INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: Let suppose I want to use the current structure so how it can be solved?

Comment: Hi, I understand, that but how can I separate the apps level urls?

Comment: As I mentioned in the answer, it is really caused by the steps you took up to this point. Django will automatically generate all the important files and folders in right structure if you took the right steps. were you following a specific document/tutorial? Maybe you were missing certain steps. I updated a bit after the file structure...for app level urls.py

Comment: I have tried same steps, but the structure is different, clients is being generated outside the project level. It is not the child of the project.

Comment: my bad!!! app should be the same level as project. I will edit it . How about your urls, do they work now?

Comment: If I use the same level, then that is working fine, but I want to keep the app as the child.

Comment: Oh? is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: It make sense that apps are under project instead of project level.

Comment: Please check my edited answer with specific command line

Comment: That is making sense, I have tried already and when I create urls file in clients app then the problem starts and I was not able to include in the project level urls file.

Comment: could you show your clients/urls.py in your question?

Comment: also what is the problem? do you have error message?

Comment: by any chance, were you using the same name for ```project``` and ```app```?

Comment: I have tried with different names aslo. I'm getting `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'clients'` error same as I posted in question.

Comment: just in cae, when you put ```clients``` in ```installed_apps```, did you put ```,``` after that?

Comment: Yes it is working using `climemanage.clients` in INSTALLED_APPS and also in urls.py but why I have to use climemanage project name before app name, why?

Comment: It is because you put your ```clients``` under ```climemanage```. Remember you wanted to have your app inside of the ```app```? If you were using the original structure I mentioned, you can just use ```clients```

Comment: I understand that and I got everything, but the things is that I was thinking to have import statement on the top `import climemanage.clients` and then just use the `clients` in the INSTALLED_APPS array. So can you tell me how django start searching apps? why it can't find the apps in the project folder without giving complete path?

Comment: Good question. I don't have a good answer top of my head. If all worked out, please kindly accept my answer. You could open another question thread for that.

Answer (score 1):

In main urls.py file you can add the following code snippet.

```
from django.urls import path, include 

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('something/', include('clients.urls')),
]
```

#### In settings.py file

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
 'django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'rest_framework',
 'webapi',  # like in my case my appname was webapi
 'nameofyourapp', #pay attention here
]
```

Comment: or 'clients.appconfig' see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59235753/django-installed-apps-is-apps-appconfig-redundant

Comment: It is not working, now it is not founding the module in `settings.py` file as django can't find the `clients` module but it can find it using dot notation as `climemanage.clients`. Have you checked my project directory structure?