# How Django search for the module/apps in project folder

Tags: django

This question is related to the following questions. [How to import urls from apps in django main urls file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090684/how-to-import-urls-from-apps-in-django-main-urls-file)

Actually I have the following project structure.

[image: Project Structure]

I want to ask why I have to use complete path link to point the apps in `INSTALLED_APPS` or even anywhere in the django files.

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'climemanage.clients',
]
```

Why I can't use just `import climemanage.clients` (or any other import statement) and use `clients` in INSTALLED_APPS ?

Same for the urls.py file I have to use the complete path as `climemanage.clients.urls` the following.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('clients/', include('climemanage.clients.urls')),
]
```

Why not just `clients.urls`? When I try to use just `clients.urls` it is giving `Module not found 'clients'`

Comment: you can just write clients.urls in include method. and you can write just your app name in installed-apps

Comment: @RezaGH it not allowing me to write, it is giving `clients` module not found error.

Comment: why your app location is in your project folder. maybe your getting error because of this

Answer (score 1):

Because Django does a number of things upon initialization of the project, that require modules to be loaded in a specific order. Importing things in settings would make that complicated as imports already execute code before Django can do anything about it.

Thus, INSTALLED_APPS is a list of strings that use importlib's `import_module`, to load modules when Django is ready for them to be loaded. This is done in `django.apps.config`.

If you want to shorten the path, you could add that path to [PYTHONPATH](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html?highlight=pythonpath#envvar-PYTHONPATH) environment variable, but think carefully, since the more paths you have in there, the more chances for duplicate names. It's generally not a good investment of time and resources to try and save typing in configuration files as once you're done configuring, you hardly get back to them.