# I am unable to import Static Files in Django website. Any on please explain what i am missing in code?

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-forms, django-templates

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

I am facing issue while loading static files in the project. I have created the folder named as static, added (JS,CSS and Image files to the folder). I have provided the path in settings.py file. Please any one explain me that what i am missing and where i have to do modifications.

```
STATIC_URL = "/static/"
STATICFILES_DIR = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]
LOGIN_URL = "account:login"
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = "public:index"

Installed Apps:
INSTALLED_APPS = [
'django.contrib.admin',
'django.contrib.auth',
'django.contrib.contenttypes',
'django.contrib.sessions',
'django.contrib.messages',
'django.contrib.staticfiles',
'website.apps.accounts',]
```

Comment: your file structure seems off. please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65090684/how-to-import-urls-from-apps-in-django-main-urls-file/65091769#65091769

Comment: did you run `python manage.py collectstatic` before running the (local) server?

Comment: Good point @ha-neul I did not even notice the lack of static folder in the app

Comment: I have the same structure which you did mentioned. I have already run python manage.py collectstatic command. Still i am facing same issue. ha-neul will you please look into my files and tell me what the hack i am missing. I have changed the structure and did a lot of experiments. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe you missed to put the STATIC_URL in your urls.py main file, as is shown in the official documentation

```
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static

urlpatterns = [
    # ... the rest of your URLconf goes here ...
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

[Link official documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-during-development)

I have already added the static root directory with in URLS.py file

[image]

Comment: I have already added the static root directory function. i have mentioned the snap shot of urls.py file.

Comment: not yet. I am onto it. Finding out what the heck I am missing.